# Accept CFSTR_FILECONTENTS/CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR int DoDrop in MFC Application

Tags: c++, mfc, drag-and-drop

I've got a MFC application (VS2010) containing a CScrollView which uses a COleDropTarget to register itself as a drop target.

This works, and I can check the type of the dropped data in the OnDrop method:

```
BOOL CMyClass::DoDrop(COleDataObject *pDataObject,  DROPEFFECT dropEffect, CPoint point)
{
    if (pDataObject->IsDataAvailable(CF_DIB))
    {
        // Do something with DIB
    }
    else if (pDataObject->IsDataAvailable(CF_ENHMETAFILE) || pDataObject->IsDataAvailable(CF_METAFILEPICT))
    {
       // Do something with Metafiles
    }
    else if (pDataObject->IsDataAvailable(CF_HDROP))
    {
        // Do something with files
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

This works nicely. Now, I would like to drop "virtual files" into this CScrollView (from another application) and I don't know how. With virtual files I mean using the CFSTR_FILECONTENTS/CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR
clipbord format and provide the actual stream of data when needed.

Providing the clipboard with virtual files is easy enough (there are tutorials out there, e.g. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23139/Transferring-Virtual-Files-to-Windows-Explorer-in) or [there](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15576/How-to-drag-a-virtual-file-from-your-app-into-Wind)),
but on the receiving end (my DoDrop method) I don't know how to retrieve the data.

The application providing the virtual files seems to work (meaning that I can drop them to the desktop).

So, can somebody tell me how I can get the data from the virtual files in my MFC DoDrop method?

Edit: Ok, following code works for me:

```
FORMATETC fetc;
// m_cfstrFileContents is CLIPFORMAT retrieved with RegisterClipboardFormat(_T("FileContents"))
fetc.cfFormat=m_cfstrFileContents; 
fetc.dwAspect=DVASPECT_CONTENT;
fetc.lindex=0;
fetc.ptd=NULL;
fetc.tymed=TYMED_ISTREAM;

// Get file contents.
STGMEDIUM stgm;
if (!pDataObject->GetData(m_cfstrFileContents, &stgm, &fetc))
{
    // We don't have virtual file contents in the clipbord.
    return FALSE;
}
COleStreamFile file(stgm.pstm);
DWORD dwLength=file.GetLength();
LPSTR pszString=(LPSTR)_alloca(dwLength+1);
file.Seek(0, CFile::begin);
file.Read(pszString, dwLength);
pszString[dwLength]='\0';
// Either close the stream or release the storage medium, not both!
//file.Close(); 

ReleaseStgMedium(&stgm);
```

So, pszString really points to the data of the transferred file, mission accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive the data you should just be able to call `pDataObject->GetData()` with the IDs for `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` and `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` (you need to call `RegisterClipboardFormat()` to get the IDs).

That will fill out your `STGMEDIUM` structure with the values required to get the virtual data, which might be provided as an `IStream` but could just as easily be provided as an `HGLOBAL` etc.

After you have finished with the data, call `ReleaseStgMedium()` function to release the `STGMEDIUM` data.

This is documented on MSDN:

[Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx)

[Using the CFSTR_FILECONTENTS Format to Extract Data from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx#filecontents)

Comment: Thanks @snowdude, I got it nearly working, only a for me unexplainable exception when releasing the STGMEDIUM remains, do you see why I'm getting it? (If not I can make another question asking specifically for the solution of this problem).

Comment: Found the solution, I can't first close the COleStream and then release the storage medium, one of them is enough.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, if you look at the code for COleStreamFile::Close() it releases the IStream pointer. Calling ReleaseStgMedium should be the preferred way.

Comment: @remy-lebeau Thanks for cleaning up my answer.