# Drag and Drop Attachments from Outlook to Windows Filesystem

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, wxpython, windows-shell

I want to handle PDF files from Outlook and Windows Explorer. The user should drag the file to a window and then I want to copy the file to a folder and do some other things with it.

I found a [nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663885/how-to-drag-and-drop-attachments-from-outlook-to-a-wxpython-application/69723850#69723850), but I couldn't find out how to handle the Outlook file. I just found the information. How can I copy the file to a folder?

I have tried to understand the sources given in the example: [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard), but my knowledge of Python is too poor.

Comment: In the example you link to, the code *owns* the target (drop) app. But you don't own Windows Explorer, so you can't handle dropped files on it, so you can do that (it has nothing to do with the language, python or other), or explain exactly what you need, there may be other solutions.